# congruence mod m application

Tags: congruences, congruence-relations

Fix m ∈ N and let a, b, c, d ∈ Z be such that a ≡ b (mod m) and c ≡ d (mod m ). How would I prove the below statement. I understand the properties of congruence mod m but not sure how to apply them.

```
a + c ≡ b + d (mod m )
```

What I have so far

a - b = k * m 
c - d = l * m

so a = km + b 
   c = lm + d

therefore a + c = km + b + lm + d 
          a + c = ( b + d) + m( k + l ) 
          (a + c) - (b + d)= m (k + l)

But I don't know how to get rid of the m(k + l) part ?

Comment: So $a = km + b$ and $c = lm + d$ for some integers $k$ and $l$. What does this tell you about $a + c$?

Comment: do we go a + c = (km + b) * (lm + d) ?

Comment: We get $a + c = km + b + lm + d$. Can you rearrange the right side of this equation to get what you need to show?

Comment: ahhh omg I get it thanks !

Comment: @manthanomen can you go a+bc=(mx+b)+(my+d)(a+c)−(b+d)=mx+my(a+c)−(b+d)=m(x+y)

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to do. First of all, what do you need to show to prove $a + c \equiv b + d \mod m$? What does that mean?

Comment: ill show you what I have so far hold on

Comment: Just edited the question and added my working

Comment: Since $k + l$ is an integer, you're done! You don't need to get rid of it. I just posted an answer below, but it's pretty much exactly what you have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $a \equiv b \mod m$ means, by definition, that $a = km + b$ for some integer $k$. Similarly, $c \equiv d \mod m$ means that $c = lm + d$ for some integer $l$. To show that $a + c = b + d \mod m$, you must show that $a + c = rm + (b + d)$ for some integer $r$ (since this is what it means to be congruent mod $m$).

We have $$a + c = km + b + lm + d = km + lm + (b + d) = (k + l)m + (b + d).$$ Since $k + l$ is an integer, we conclude that $a + c \equiv b + d \mod m$.